# How to wrap text around 2 divs

Tags: css

I have 2 divs

```
div A
div B
```

div B is below div A. When I set flow left on div B text on right side starts next to div B.

```
<div A>
<div B>  -----> some text....
```

What I need to do to force text next to div A?

```
<div A> -----> need text next to div A
<div B>
```

I did try flow left on div A but then div B is being moved next to div A, which is not what I want.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean "float", not "flow", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
<div id="container" style="float: left">
    <div id="a">blah blah blah</div>
    <div id="b">foo bar baz</div>
</div>
lorem ipsem dolor sit amet
```

would give you something like

```
blah blah   lorem 
blah        ipsum
foo bar     dolor
baz         sit amet
```

with a bit more styling applied to the divs.

Comment: Thanks, I did create another div around those 2, float it to the left and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

To have div b always appear below div a, and have text float around div a, float div a to the left, and on div b, use `clear:left; float:left`

Comment: Thanks, I did try it but it doesn't work. Does it make a defference if those divs are wrapers ? like div.image-wrapper and div.link-wrapper ?

Comment: Maybe if you posted the actual code you're using we could come up with better answers.

Comment: Thanks, as Marc B suggested creating another div around those 2 seems to work.